# Number of ways to distribute $N$ distinct objects into $M$ distinct boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

There are $N$ distinct objects and i want to distribute them into $M$ distinct boxes .No balls have to be left without box but there can be empty boxes.

I tried myself to find answer by trying approaches similar to stars and bars method but didn't reached the solution after considerable efforts.

Note : this problem is not related to the problem linked . I think answer of this problem is $M^N$ .Since each ball can be put into $M$ boxes thus the answer.

Comment: How many balls may a box end up holding?

Comment: Likely any number between 0 and N in a box.

Comment: [Distinct balls into distinct boxes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328985/distinct-balls-into-distinct-boxes?rq=1).

Comment: Nice find, @Invisible

Comment: @Invisible That post is related to probability i guess and does not answer my question .

Comment: @amWhy I think total number of ways is $M^N$ since for each ball i have $M$ options  .

Comment: Your argument means you can, e. g., put all the balls in one box and then do it repeatedly with the copies you don't have.

Comment: @Invisible yes putting all $N$ even in one single box is allowed

Comment: If you put one ball in a box, you can't put it into another before taking all the balls out and distributing them again, but in a different way.